# spring boot command line run not using logback-spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

This app works fine in IntelliJ and creates the log files as per configurations, however when launched the app from command line its not using logback-spring.xml file and instead goes on to create *tmp/spring.log file which seems to coming from spring *logback/base.xml.
I have spent couple of days to troubleshoot this issue but nothing seems to work so far and other questions do not address the underlying issue, your help is appreciated.

I am launching the app as -

```
java -jar abc.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

I can see that logback-spring.xml is present inside abc.jar as

BOOT-INF/classes/ logback-spring.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find how to configure `logback` with `spring-boot` [howto.logging.logback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging.logback)

With `src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <!-- include spring boot file-appender -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> <!-- add file-appender -->
    </root>
    <logger name="com.example" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

And providing a logging file-name in `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
logging.file.name=application.log
```

You should see a file application.log in the same directory as you launched your application with

`java -jar your-app.jar --spring.profiles.active=test`

Comment: I was also including base.xml as well that seem to be real issue.